# Find Blank array and unset/remove object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I am stuck in Laravel, Need expert's help to resolve the issue.

I have multidimentional array, i am developing the api. I have tried to unset it but somehow it throws the error. I have tried to go with array_filter as well, but not possible for me to resolve the issue.

```
$data =
    Array
(
    [dno] => LUCYELEC
    [mcu] => 007801714078
    [type] => analytic
    [start] => 191018120000
    [end] => 191020115900
    [events] => Array
        (
        )

)
Array
(
    [dno] => LUCYELEC
    [mcu] => 106214191003
    [type] => analytic
    [start] => 191018120000
    [end] => 191020115900
    [events] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [feebbb] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [date-time] => 191018080000
                                    [sub-type] => PQ
                                    [comments] => sdfas
                                    [parameter-list] => sdfasd
                                    [state] => bad
                                    [value] => 9200
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

There are some [events] are blank, no array. SO i want to remove it and get the only array oject which has data.
I need to create this in Loop like forench or for loop.

Response formate in json

```
return response()->json(['data'=>$data)]);
```

Comment: where are the codes?

Comment: HI Kevin, It is attached with the post only. There is array.

Comment: You are expected to show some effort of solving the problem yourself before asking a question here. Also please refer to [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply next foreach loop:

```
foreach($data as $ind=>$record){
     if(empty($record['events'])) unset($data[$ind]);
}

sort($data); // <-- makes indexes begin from 0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, I check this but seens it unset all the records. All array goes blank.

Comment: @vdr, [https://3v4l.org/t7NDl](https://3v4l.org/t7NDl)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397526/how-to-discourage-rushed-answers-on-questions-that-should-be-closed